# wso2 identity server issue with '@' symbol

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We have LDAP groups in an existing directory that we are trying to connect to WSO2IS.

These LDAP groups have the @ (at) symbol in their name. This apparently causes issues with identity server 4.5.0.  WSO2 prohibits users from adding a new external role with that symbol. And when groups are already in LDAP with an @ symbol, they display as blank rows.

The SOAP response shows the groups return, but with the '@' symbol stripped from the name. Again - a blank row appears for that role.

Is there a way for WSO2 to support this character in an LDAP group?

---

UPDATE: I found the property for regular expressions in user-mgt.xml. I added the '@' symbol to it and it allowed me to enter an internal role that started with an '@':

```
<Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9.@_-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
```

However, even after this change, when I pull in a group from LDAP that begins with '@', this '@' character is stripped out of the response. Example:
LDAP group name: @test123
This shows up in the SOAP response as:

> test123

Is this a bug or is there a missing config property that I am missing which is instructing WSO2 to strip out this character?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

In the current implementation, WSO2IS does not allowed to use @ sign in the role name. Because @ sign is used to concatenate string value apart from role name and due to that you see this behavior.